# Question on Sum Rule of the counting principle

Tags: combinatorics

Question: Ministry of Education are inviting tender for four categories promoting the use of IT in education. Each category consists of $5$, $4$, $3$, and $7$ projects, respectively. Each project appears on exactly one category. How many possible projects are there to choose from? Explain your answer.

My Answer: $(5+4)+(4+4)+(3+3)+(7+4)=9+8+6+11=34$ possible projects to choose from. I used the sum rule here.

Is this correct?

Comment: Each project appears in exactly one category.  Add the numbers for each category.  What does that give you?

Answer (score 1):

Since each project appears in exactly one category, the four lists of projects can be combined into one list of projects containing $5 + 4 + 3 + 7 = 19$ projects.  Hence, there are $19$ projects from which to choose.

The [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) (or Sum Rule) states that if there are $n_1$ ways of performing one task and $n_2$ ways of performing another task that cannot be performed at the same time, there are $n_1 + n_2$ ways of performing both tasks.

In this case, we can select a project from category one in five ways, a project from category two in four ways, a project from category three in three ways, or a project in category four in seven ways.  Since it is not possible to choose the same project from more than one list, the Addition Principle applies.  Hence, there is a total of $5 + 4 + 3 + 7 = 19$ projects from which to choose.